# How to return a type from C++ functions?

Tags: c++, function, templates, return-type

I'm reading *C++ Templates: The Complete Guide, 2th Edition*, And i see this code:

```cpp
template<typename T1, typename T2>
std::common_type_t<T1, T2> max (T1 a, T2 b)
{
    return b < a ? a : b;
}
```

According to what I've read from page 12, I want to ask how function figures the type it wants to return? In the above example, how `max` function figures the type it wants to return, choosing between T1 and T2?

I looked in : `./gcc/libstdc++-v3/include/std/type_traits`*:2115* but could not figure out what happened.

**WHAT I WANT TO DO:**
I have a lot of `typedef`ed function pointer like this:

```c
typedef void (*voidVoid)();
typedef void (*voidInt)(int);
typedef void (*voidDouble)(double);
...
```

And i want to make a function like:

```cpp
Type getFunctionPointer(const std::string& name);
```

Which take name of function-pointer and return corresponding function-pointer. Before I find `template`s I thought it's not possible. But I think, `std::commone_type_t` is exactly doing what I want to do. It take a variable and return a type (Which is type of that variable).

How can I define that? Can I implement it with `std::commone_type_t` or a better solution, just with `templates`?

Comment: What do you mean? A function always has a some return type specified.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica, How `std::common_type_t` specified the `max` function return type ?

Comment: So you are asking how `std::common_type_t` works?

Comment: `std::max` is a function template and the return type depends on the arguments. `std::common_type_t` is an alias to `std::common_type::type`.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica, My primary question is how we could return a type from function ?, And `std::common_type_t` is a example.

Comment: Again, what do you mean by "return a type from a function"?

Comment: Note the possible implementation here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/common_type It's not a function.

Comment: `std::common_type_t` is not a function.

Comment: Usually you would write a class template and one property is the type.

Comment: @GhasemRamezani You don't return a type. You return a value of a certain type.

Comment: Do you maybe want to return an object, that describes a type like the `Type`-class of C#? Or do you mean to return either `T1` or `T2` depending on what value is larger? I'm really puzzled.

Comment: You mean like `int my_func(int a, int b) // returns int`?

Comment: @TedLyngmo, You mean `std::common_type::type` (as Thomas told is an alias) return a value ? what happened to declaration of `max` template function ?

Comment: @GhasemRamezani No I don't. As Bob_ and  IlCapitano mentioned, `std::common_type_t` is not a function. It does not return anything.

Comment: Regarding your edit: You cannot return a type from a function. `std::common_type_t<T1, T2>` is not a function. It is a type alias template, that depending on its template arguments aliases a different type. It cannot be used in place of a value. Conditional types like this can only be conditioned on compile-time known types and values. `std::string` never has a compile time usable value, so you can never condition a type on its value. C++ is statically-typed, so a type of an expression can never depend on a runtime value.

Answer (score 5):

Your question does not make sense. This function:

```
template<typename T1, typename T2>
std::common_type_t<T1, T2> max (T1 a, T2 b)
{
    return b < a ? a : b;
}
```

does not return the type `std::common_type_t<T1, T2>`. It returns a value (either a or b), and the type of the value is `std::common_type_t<T1, T2>`.

In the same way, this function:

```
int max2 (int a, int b)
{
    return b < a ? a : b;
}
```

returns a value of type `int`, but does not return the type `int` itself.

If you want to write a function that returns a value of another type, for example `std::string`, you write it before the function name:

```
vvvvvvvvvvv here
std::string return_a_string ()
{
    return "hello";
}
```

Comment: It's like i don't explain my question very well. I know all that you write (and thank you), But i what to know how `std::common_type<T1, T2>` return a `type` ? when we call `max(23.3, 32.34)` the `std::common_type<T1, T2>` will be `double` and `max` template function return a value of type `double`. How `std::common_type` return `type` instead of a value ?

Comment: `std::common_type` is not a function, it is a class template. (`std::common_type_t` is an alias that is basically short for `std::common_type::type`)